# Why does the MAX3232 have two inputs and two outputs?

Tags: rs232, max3232

I am trying to make a PCB for TTL to RS232 converter. I am using the [MAX3232](https://www.snapeda.com/parts/MAX3232ESE+/Maxim%20Integrated/datasheet/).

[image]

It looks 10-11, 14-7, 13-8 and 12-9 are the same. I see some diagrams where people only use one of them. For example,in this diagram:

[image]

What should I do? Connect both or just one?

I am trying to make something like this:

[image]

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Many RS232 peripherals use control signals, e.g. CTS/RTS, in addition to the TX/RX data lines, so they would need another transmitter/receiver.

If you plan to make a general purpose RS232-DB9 module, you can use them as CTS/RTS signals or any other signal that would suit your need.

Here's a picture of the various RS232-DB9 connector pins ([source](https://www.bb-elec.com/Learning-Center/All-White-Papers/Serial/FAQ-RS-232-Connections-That-Work.aspx)):

[image: RS232 pinout]

Comment: This is a horrible diagram. The arrows make no sense as flow of data is concerned.

Comment: @TheValyreanGroup Why would you say so? That is perfectly informative picture for a straight cable. The diagrams for crossover cables at the provided link are even more useful.

Comment: @Maple No. The crossover diagrams at that link are just as bad. A RX port does not send to a TX port, it goes the the other way. So the arrows are even backwards for that. And on a straight cable, there is no “direction” (there is, but it can’t be expressed this way) so there should be no arrows.

Comment: @TheValyreanGroup I strongly recommend you to read up on RS-232 protocol, it seems you confuse it with UART. In RS-232 world there is no "RX port" or "TX port", there are DTE and DCE ports. Furthermore, the signals are named from the DTE perspective,  so RX pin on DCE does send data to RX pin on DTE device or TX pin on another DCE device.

Answer (score 11):

It has two inputs and two outputs. What you do with them or not depends on what your application requires.

You can make an RS232 adapter with two RS232 ports that both only support TXD/RXD, or you can make one port that supports RTS/CTS handshaking too, or you can choose to leave parts of it unused like on any other logic gate.

And like with any other logic gate, you must read the datasheet if an input can be left unconnected due to internal biasing, or does it require to be connected to some potential like VCC or GND.

Although if such a board already exists, consider if it is worth making it yourself or buying.

Comment: "Connect unused inputs to GND or Vcc" — this particular datasheet :)

Comment: @hobbs you can connect them to either potential you want, whichever is more convenient for your PCB layout. The datasheets of both Maxim and TI mention it.

Answer (score 3):

I would only say that there is also **2 others outputs** ... generally not known and not used !

Theoretically, **~ +5V** and ~ **-5V** ... (**~ +9V** and **~ -9V** if "some" supplied with +5 V) which can be used for bipolar **supplying op amps** having **low quiescent currents** ... (**pin 6 and pin 2** in the OP picture, it should be *interesting*  use of 1 uF capacitors C1-C2-C3-C4 in this case). From MAX232 note,  [link](https://datasheets.maximintegrated.com/en/ds/MAX220-MAX249.pdf) page 4.

[image]

https://www.renesas.com/eu/en/document/dst/icl232-datasheet , **see figure 11**.

***Additional remark** : I have found a remark ([? for old products](https://electrosome.com/solving-max232-max3232-heating-or-burning-problem/)) about C3.
It was better (?) to connect Capacitor C3 to VCC (5V) such that it is compatible to both Texas Instruments and Maxim Integrated chips ( [MAX220-MAX249](https://datasheets.maximintegrated.com/en/ds/MAX220-MAX249.pdf), C3 pin 2 connected to Vcc). And Renesas too ... All are now "aligned" for connecting pin 2 at Vcc or ground ([TRSF3232](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/trsf3232.pdf?ts=1632724945712&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.ti.com%252Fproduct%252FTRSF3232%253FkeyMatch%253D3232) , [TRS202](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/trs202.pdf)).*

Comment: For C3, max3232 datasheet shows that connect to GND, but at your link shows connect to 5v, on the other hand max3232 datasheet has a note which is "* C3 CAN BE RETURNED TO EITHER VCC OR GROUND". So i think it is not important, isnt it? or there are special reason to connect 5v for you

Comment: @mehmet     If I remembered well, for some manufacturer, these circuits had to be connected to +5V. Will search this comparative note I had found. Added the link in answer. But not really an explanation ... Now either Vcc or ground.